# В чём ошибка в последней строке? Питон выводит ошибку, написано следующее:"TypeError: 'str' object is not callable", что делать?

Tags: python, строки

```
    what = input ('Что делаем? : (+, -)')

    
    if what == '+':
      a = float(input('Первое число:'))
      b = float(input('Второе число:'))
      c = a + b
      print("Результат:" + str(c))
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Кем пишется? Что именно пишется?

Answer (score 3):

Где то выше имени `str` или `print` присвоена какая-то строка. Нельзя использовать зарезервированные имена для своих переменных.

Comment: Что именно мне нужно исправить?

Comment: @FGF нужно просмотреть весь свой код, и найти, где у вас есть присвоение `str = ....` (перезапись функции `str` каким-то значением). Как исправить - не делать этого, использовать другое имя.

Answer (score 0):

Приведённый код рабочий:

```
In [2]:  a = float(input('Первое число:'))
   ...:  b = float(input('Второе число:'))
   ...:  c = a + b
   ...:  print("Результат:" + str(c))
Первое число:1
Второе число:2
Результат:3.0
```

Если ошибка, то она в другом месте

Comment: Опять та же ошибка

Answer (score 0):

`str` - строковый тип, а выводится значение `c` с типом `int`.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Что мне нужно написать вместо str?